# AngularJS - How to retain UI state when using $resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In my app users can create/delete items. I use $resources and it works like a charm. But I want to show a loading-screen whenever a request is in progress.

```
// show loading-screen
// ...

Item.destroy({'id': item.id}, function( response ){
  // handle success
  // ...

  // hide loading-screen
}, function( error ){
  // handle error 
  // ...

  // hide loading-screen
});
```

But instead of show/hide the loading-screen everytime I write a resource-call I rather would configure the resourcemodule so show/hide loading-screen will be automatically called whenever a resource is loading data.

Is there a way to configure the resourcemodule to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$http.pendingRequests` array to see if there are some pending requests.

Example from angular-seed project : https://github.com/rpeterson/angular-seed/blob/master/client/src/common/services/httpRequestTracker.coffee :

```
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', [])

.factory('httpRequestTracker', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        var httpRequestTracker = {};
        httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function() {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };

        return httpRequestTracker;
    }
]);
```

Then you just have to create a dedicated loading directive with `ng-show="httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests"` for example

Note that with this solution you just know if there is  a pending request, you don't know which one (can be tricky if you have multi-ajax request on your page)